# Unable to catch DbUpdateConcurrencyException and throw UserFriendlyException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, aspnetboilerplate, optimistic-concurrency

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate with Code-First Entity Framework and MVC 5.
I want to handle concurrency. In the `Update` method, I put `Timestamp` data annotation for `RowVersion` field in my entity.

In the manager of my entity and in `Update` operation, I am trying to catch `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` exception and throw `UserFriendlyException` but because `UpdateAsync` is asynchronous, I don't know where to handle the exception.

Where should I handle this exception to be user-friendly and not to see Internal Server Error?

```
public abstract class BaseFullAuditedEntity : FullAuditedEntity<Guid>
{
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public class Branch : BaseFullAuditedEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Manager code:

```
public interface IBranchManager : IDomainService
{
    Task<Branch> Update(Branch branch, byte[] RowVersion);
}

public class BranchManager : DomainService, IBranchManager
{
    private IRepository<Branch, Guid> _branchRepository { get; }

    public async Task<Branch> Update(Branch branch, byte[] RowVersion)
    {
        try
        {
            return await _branchRepository.UpdateAsync(branch);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException("Update Concurrency Happened");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i applied the same solution you suggested before you answered me, and it was exactly what i wrote  that what made me more sure now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UpdateAsync(branch)` only adds `branch` to the context.

Inject `IUnitOfWorkManager` and `await` `SaveChangesAsync()`:

```cs
try
{
    await _branchRepository.UpdateAsync(branch);
    await _unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync(); // Add this
    return branch;
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    throw new UserFriendlyException("Update Concurrency Happened");
}
```

Alternatively, override `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` in your `DbContext` to catch for all entities:

```cs
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    try
    {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        throw new UserFriendlyException("Update Concurrency Happened");
    }
}

public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    try
    {
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        throw new UserFriendlyException("Update Concurrency Happened");
    }
}
```

Comment: solution looks promising... you need to `SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 1):

Try catching as an aggregate exception...
(Sometimes, the real exception is being wrapped.)

```
try
{
    // code...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is AggregateException)
    {
        var exMsg = FlattenAggregate((AggregateException)ex);
        throw new UserFriendlyException(exMsg );
    }

    throw;
}
```

---

```
public static string FlattenAggregate(AggregateException aggregateException)
{
    var sbErr = new StringBuilder();
    var exceptions = aggregateException.Flatten();
    foreach (var exception in exceptions.InnerExceptions)
    {
        sbErr.AppendLine(exception.ToString());
    }

    return sbErr.ToString();
}
```